# SwiftUI in target (custom keyboard)

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, custom-keyboard

Can't find any example of using SwiftUI in Keyboard Extension.
I create an extension and trying to create simple `SwiftUI` `Button` with no action (it just prints debug text). But there is no visible button in Keyboard.
Is it possible to create SwiftUI custom keyboard?

```
struct SwiftUIButton: View{
    let action: () -> ()
    var body: some View{
        Button(action: action){Text("Tap me")}
    }
}

class KeyboardViewController: UIInputViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet var nextKeyboardButton: UIButton!


//1.insert this: SwiftUIButton is a simple Button View
    var swiftUIButtonView: SwiftUIButton!
    //...
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        

        // Perform custom UI setup here

        //2. try to insert my SwiftUI View
        let swiftUIButtonView = SwiftUIButton(action: {print("test")})
        let vc = UIHostingController(rootView: swiftUIButtonView)
        //I tried that with no success
        //guard let inputView = inputView else { return }
        //inputView.addSubview(vc.view)
        self.view.addSubview(vc.view)

        //all that following code is standard from Xcode
        self.nextKeyboardButton = UIButton(type: .system)

        self.nextKeyboardButton.setTitle(NSLocalizedString("Next Keyboard", comment: "Title for 'Next Keyboard' button"), for: [])
        self.nextKeyboardButton.sizeToFit()
        self.nextKeyboardButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        self.nextKeyboardButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleInputModeList(from:with:)), for: .allTouchEvents)

        self.view.addSubview(self.nextKeyboardButton)

        self.nextKeyboardButton.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leftAnchor).isActive = true
        self.nextKeyboardButton.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    }
```

When I try to test it in simulator, I see empty Keyboard

[image]

and some errors in debug console:

> 2020-01-23 02:07:13.421876+0300 SwiftUIKeyboard[4723:376225] Failed to
> inherit CoreMedia permissions from 4717: (null) 2020-01-23
>
> 02:07:13.460713+0300 SwiftUIKeyboard[4723:375598] [External]
> -[UIInputViewController needsInputModeSwitchKey] was called before a connection was established to the host application. This will produce
> an inaccurate result. Please make sure to call this after your primary
> view controller has been initialized.

last message repeats 6 times.

What am I doing wrong?
Or do I need to create UIKit Keyboard View and implement SwiftUI inside of it?

Comment: I'm a new to Swift and started with `SwiftUI`. So I don't know how does `UIKit` works:(
Is there some simple instructions how to implement `SwiftUI` `View` to `UIKit` in `UIInputViewController`? Or I have to start it over again and learn `UIKit`?

Comment: Any luck with understanding the other error message? `[UIInputViewController needsInputModeSwitchKey] was called...`

Comment: @yaronalk not yet. I didn't find any bad behavior with globe key yet, so I just ignore it right now.

Comment: @Aspid any idea on this why is this warning is showing ? I could not quite get it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

oh it was rough to deal with UIKit, but I made it.

```
    // Perform custom UI setup here
    let child = UIHostingController(rootView: SwiftUIButton())
    //that's wrong, it must be true to make flexible constraints work
   // child.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    child.view.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
    view.addSubview(child.view)
    addChild(child)//not sure what is this for, it works without it.
```

works fine. Even GeometryReader inside of SwiftUI View gets bounds well.